# Django get absolute url of Rest framework view

Tags: python, django

In my django application I am trying to get the absolute url of an endpoint view which is defined as follows:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        return queryset
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'products', ProductViewSet, base_name="product")

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse    
class Product(models.Model):
        uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid1)
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('product', kwargs={'uuid': self.uuid})
```

however when I do this and try to get the url for a specific product I get an error `Reverse for 'product' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'uuid': UUID('d89-f530')}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

I tried different things but the error is still same, I am not sure how `urlresolver` works with DRF router view.

just as a side note, I am using django 1.10

Any help on this would be really appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Are you including your URLs in a namespace? You can use `manage.py show_urls` with `django-extensions` to get a complete list of URLs and verify you're asking for the right name.

Comment: You are the man dude, wish I would have known this command first, huh !! anyway Thanks a ton, it worked

Comment: I am having kind of the same problem. Can you post the solution?